# iAd UIImageView memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, iad

Running my app on device using Instruments tells me that iAd is leaking on a UIImageView (namely the ad). Does anyone know what this is about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Raise a bug report with Apple

Answer (score 1):

You need to release iAd in viewDidUnload

Comment: releasing the iAd in viewDidUnload instead of dealloc seemed to fix the problem