# iAds are leaking memory

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, iad

I recently implemented iads by following the WWDC video.  However, while testing with leaks I found that my ads were leaking. I heard that this is a known problem with iads.  Someone mentioned that releasing the banner in viewDidUnload might help but that didn't work for me... Does anyone know any way around these leaks?  Even though the leaks are pretty small, I have many view controllers displaying them throughout my app and the leaks quickly add up

Comment: "Iads" looks like "lads". I had to fix the title. :)

Comment: Did you file a bug report yet?  stackoverflow is a great resource, but it's not nearly as productive as reporting the bugs you encounter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding AdBannerView to application creates memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499793/adding-adbannerview-to-application-creates-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few people saying that there was a leak because the iAd wasn't being released. Check the following:

[iAd UIImageView memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332272/iphone-ipod-touch-iad-uiimageview-memory-leak)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54834-iad-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Ya I saw both of those posts and tried their solutions but still no luck.  Thanks for the response though!